# How to verify secure communicaion after using TLS in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Hyperledger Fabric we use **TLS** for secure communication between nodes. So how do I verify/check secure communication between two nodes in HLF after enabling TLS communication?

I have two Fabcar examples, one with **TLS enable** and one **without TLS enabled**. so how do I check/verify the result of two codes? I should get the difference in the results of both the codes.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple test you might run wireshark to inspect the packages to the two HLF's where Wireshark should be able to tell you if the traffic is TLS or not, based on the packages.

[This link](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/21257/how-does-wireshark-determine-the-protocol) explain some basics to how wireshark detect package types. [And here](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2017/05/12/dissecting-tls-using-wireshark/) how it detect TLS.

With some strategic [filters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) it should not be a too big of problem to check the specific packages for HLF's. There might even exist some finished filters for this on google.